# Javascript Undefined Variable Before Function

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this chunk of javascript that's kind of hacked around from http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1248 and I am seeing an error of "undefined variable - broadcast".

```
function cdtd(broadcast) {
    /* expected date format is Month DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS */
    var nextbroadcast = new Date(broadcast);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = nextbroadcast.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<a href=\"flconlineservices.php\">Internet broadcast in progress<\/a>";
        /* Run any code needed for countdown completion here */
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days + " d";
    document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours + " h";
    document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes + " m";
    // seconds isn't in our html code (javascript error if this isn't commented out)
    /*document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = seconds + " s";*/
    var timer = setTimeout('cdtd(broadcast)',1000);
}
```

"broadcast" is passed from the page with this `<script type="text/javascript">cdtd("<?php echo $nextbroadcast; ?>");</script>`.  $nextbroadcast is based upon the date/time when the user views the page.

I tried `var broadcast;`, `var broadcast = "";`, and `var broadcast = null;`.  Whenever I try to declare the variable, before the function, it breaks the script.

Am I doing something incorrectly?  The script is working, just fine, but I'd rather not have the error.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes around the PHP?

Comment: @AlexW I just tried removing the quotes and it broke the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line:

`var timer = setTimeout('cdtd(broadcast)',1000);`

To this:

`var timer = setTimeout(function() { cdtd(broadcast); }, 1000);`

Comment: That fixed it.  I'm not particularly sure why, though.  broadcast was used twice before it got to that function.

Comment: Yes, but in your original code you were passing a string 'cdtd(broadcast)', but this parameter doesn't support functions that take parameters, so the javascript engine was looking for a function called **cdtd(broadcast)()**, which doesn't exist. You need to provide an anonymous function in order to call one with parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This might be where the problem is:

```
var timer = setTimeout('cdtd(broadcast)',1000);
```

You should declare `var timer;` above `cdtd()` function, and then set it like so *below* or *outside* of the function:

```
var func = 'cdtd(' + broadcast + ')';

timer = setTimeout(func,1000);
```

Comment: Not sure this is required, the value of `broadcast` is already available, it was passed to the function to begin with. It should be able to use what it's already got for the next time it's called. This is what I believe doubleJ was trying to achieve. See my answer.

Comment: That would have worked if the javascript was in the php file.  I had a similar thing, initially, because I didn't know how to pass a variable to an external javascript.